# New deployment isn't reflected on custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, subdomain

I uploaded my site a few months ago and it is since deployed on my custom domain: http://viamotion.viadialog.com.br/

Today, I wanted to update the site and the new version was deployed on http://viamotion-br.appspot.com/ but my custom domain still shows the previous version.

1. Why? In this case, I'm not talking about DNS propagation since nothing has changed at the DNS setup level.
2. Going to the old GAE admin console (for some reason, I couldn't find this menu in the new one), no domain is listed in domain setup. I don't remember the process I went through when assigning my site to my custom domain but I'm pretty sure it should have been in this section (and my CNAME points to ghs.googlehosted.com.). I tried to add my domain (again) but once I get to the Google Apps Admin console and see that the domain viadialog.com.br is verified (as an additional domain of the main Google Apps account), I have no option to "push" it to GAE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This answer *might* be related to the procedure you used before: https://support.google.com/a/answer/91077.

Check your particular GAE app mappings via Google Apps: in the Google Apps Admin console (https://admin.google.com/AdminHome) under the **More Controls** menu at the bottom there still is an "App Engine apps" icon (you can drag it above to later access it directly) in which you can configure particular domain mappings for each of your apps. Apparently this configuration is moving to the Developer Console by the end of the month (wondering if what you're observing wouldn't be somehow related to this transition).

Comment: Sounds relevant. Unfortunately, I just have admin rights on the domains functionality of Google Apps admin and only for a specific additional domain so I can't test it. I'll have to wait for the end of the month. In the meantime, I'm stuck with an obsolete version of my site and no way to update it without changing the DNS.

Comment: Just crossed my mind - also check your web page caching configs - you *might* be getting the old pages via intermediate caches, in which case you'd probably have to wait until those caches expire.